# How to combine HTML and an attachment using PHP mail?

Tags: php, html, email, attachment

**RESOLVED**: The issue was a missing "\r\n" at the tail end of the line reading:

```
. "Contact " . $from . " for tech support."
```

Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions!

I'm trying to make a PHP function that will send an email with some HTML body and an attached image. I've perused several of the answers on this site and online tutorials and I'm unable to see where I'm going wrong. My current code attaches an image and sends the email successfully but the HTML body is missing and I receive an empty email with my attached image.

The raw source of the email I receive appears to have my HTML in it however none of my email clients render this HTML. See the source below:

```
Return-path: <sidesul6@slan-550-84.anhosting.com>
Envelope-to: admin@sideapps.com
Delivery-date: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 18:20:36 -0600
Received: from sidesul6 by slan-550-84.anhosting.com with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <sidesul6@slan-550-84.anhosting.com>)
    id 1Wshtc-003XAD-04
    for admin@sideapps.com; Thu, 05 Jun 2014 18:20:36 -0600
To: admin@sideapps.com
Subject: attachmentTest
X-PHP-Script: sideapps.com/phpMail/mailFunc.php for 74.70.70.214
From:noreply@sideapps.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="12cbb4220ad618027879b43ba5293d9d"
Message-Id: <E1Wshtc-003XAD-04@slan-550-84.anhosting.com>
Date: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 18:20:36 -0600

Sorry, your client doesn't support MIME types.
Contact noreply@sideapps.com for tech support.--12cbb4220ad618027879b43ba5293d9d
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Testing <i><b>HTML</b></i> right now.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
--12cbb4220ad618027879b43ba5293d9d
Content-Type: image/png; name="test.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-disposition: attachment; file="test.png"

<base64 image encoding>
```

See my function below:

```
function GetHTML()
{
    return <<<HTML

    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Testing <i><b>HTML</b></i> right now.</p>
        </body>
    </html>

HTML;
}

function mailAttachment($to, $subject, $body, $from, $photoPath, $photoName, $filetype)
{
    $bound_text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));;
    $bound = "--" . $bound_text . "\r\n";
    $bound_last = "--" . $bound_text . "--\r\n";

    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "Return-Path: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

    $message =  "Sorry, your client doesn't support MIME types.\r\n"
    . "Contact " . $from . " for tech support."
    . $bound;

    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    . $body . "\r\n"
    . $bound;

    $file = file_get_contents($photoPath);

    $message .= "Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    . "Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
    . $bound_last;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
    {
         echo 'MAIL SENT!' . '<br>';
         echo 'to: ' . $to . '<br>';
         echo 'from: ' . $from . '<br>';
         echo 'bodyText: ' . $body . '<br>';
         echo 'photoPath: ' . $photoPath . '<br>';
         echo 'photoName: ' . $photoName . '<br>';
         echo 'filetype: ' . $filetype . '<br>';
    } 
    else 
    { 
         echo 'MAIL FAILED';
    }
}

mailAttachment('admin@sideapps.com', 'attachmentTest', GetHTML(),
               'noreply@sideapps.com', 'testImage.png', 'uploaded.png', 'image/png');
```

Comment: Save yourself a major headache: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: var_dump $body and see what you are getting when it is passed into the function.

Comment: Thanks @relentless but I've already been killing myself over this for a few hours and would love to finish up the function.

Comment: @VikingBlooded here is the output of var_dump: string(37) "Testing HTML right now.". It's just a simple string (the word HTML is embedded in <b> and <i> tags).

Comment: Show us the code where you build $body

Comment: @VikingBlooded I'm passing the following string to the function (defined in the function call): "Testing <i><b>HTML</b></i> right now."

Comment: show us the form code where $body is being built because it looks like it's not making it into the function.

Comment: @VikingBlooded I'm not sure I follow... I've added the function call to my post. The echo on the successful mail() call displays $body as one would expect. You can run this script yourself at http://sideapps.com/phpMail/mailFunc.php if you'd like.

Comment: MIME is really picky about line endings. Try using just \n instead of \r\n

Comment: Yeah, its what I am looking at too, when I pull everything out and run it through my browser with manually set variables, I get the mime type message and everything comes out as a string

Comment: @IMSoP thanks for the suggestion - no luck with that.

Comment: @VikingBlooded Are you running the PHP and receiving an email with the MIME type message? That would be strange... Both Gmail and my own server haven't had that problem. I get a message with the appropriate header information and attached image (no MIME error) - just with HTML missing. We should probably take this conversation to chat but it seems I don't have enough cred quite yet.

Comment: Id use: http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: @Juan it's looking like I may have to resort to one of these solutions (swiftmailer looks great) to keep myself from going insane. At the same time I HATE getting this close to a solution and throwing in the towel. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missing "\r\n" at the tail end of the line reading:

```
. "Contact " . $from . " for tech support."
```

Below is the ammended function:

```
function GetHTML()
{
    return <<<HTML

    <html>
        <body>
            <p>Testing <i><b>HTML</b></i> right now.</p>
        </body>
    </html>

HTML;
}

function mailAttachment($to, $subject, $body, $from, $photoPath, $photoName, $filetype)
{
    $bound_text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));;
    $bound = "--" . $bound_text . "\r\n";
    $bound_last = "--" . $bound_text . "--\r\n";

    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "Return-Path: " . $from . "\r\n"
    . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
    . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

    $message =  "Sorry, your client doesn't support MIME types.\r\n"
    . "Contact " . $from . " for tech support.\r\n"
    . $bound;

    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
    . $body . "\r\n"
    . $bound;

    $file = file_get_contents($photoPath);

    $message .= "Content-Type: $filetype; name=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
    . "Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"$photoName\"\r\n"
    . "\r\n"
    . chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
    . $bound_last;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
    {
         echo 'MAIL SENT!' . '<br>';
         echo 'to: ' . $to . '<br>';
         echo 'from: ' . $from . '<br>';
         echo 'bodyText: ' . $body . '<br>';
         echo 'photoPath: ' . $photoPath . '<br>';
         echo 'photoName: ' . $photoName . '<br>';
         echo 'filetype: ' . $filetype . '<br>';
    } 
    else 
    { 
         echo 'MAIL FAILED';
    }
}

mailAttachment('admin@sideapps.com', 'attachmentTest', GetHTML(),
               'noreply@sideapps.com', 'testImage.png', 'uploaded.png', 'image/png');
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't attach a file, but you can embed an image within the HTML. Looks like you have the attachment part sorted though. Perhaps this will help with the html content.

This code works in a work environment stuck in 2007, haven't fully tested it with modern browsers, versions of Outlook past 2007, etc.

IIRC, the trick was embedding the full html into the email body and working with tables.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">     
        table#bodyTable {}
        table#emailContainer {}
    </style>
    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="bodyTable">
      <tr><td align="center" valign="top"> 
          <div style="overflow: hidden;">
           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800" id="emailContainer">
            <tr><td align="center" valign="top">
                <table style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:13px" width="500" align="center">
                 <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td style="padding:10px;color:#000000;" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                   <div style="margin: 15px;float:left;">
                     <a href="http://image.link.redirect" target="_blank"><img alt="YourImageAltText" border="0" src="http://your.domain/img/yourImage.jpg" height="48" width="230" /></a>                                          
                   </div>
                  </td></tr>            
                  <tr><td style="padding:18px 30px 10px;font-size:11px" align="left">
                   <div style="font-size:12px">
                     This email is to confirm your recent job submission 
                   </div>                   
                   </tr></td>               
                  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff"><td style="padding:10px;color:#000000" align="center"></td></tr>
                </table>                            
              </td></tr>
             </table><!-- End central content table, fixed width, aligned to center based upon master table -->
           </div> 
         </td></tr>
    </table><!-- end master containing table -->
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:
I build the $msg string with dynamic content and an external template, using
include('./templates/teamNotificationEmailBody.php');

```
function orderMail($sendTo, $subject, $msg, $errorRedirect, $successRedirect) {

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: DoNotReply@Wherever.com';

if (isset($sendTo)) 
{  
    $email = filter_var($sendTo, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {    
        echo "<hr/>$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>Please return to the reservation form and enter a valid email address.<hr/><br/><a href=\"$errorRedirect\">Return $errorRedirect</a><br/>";  
        exit();
    }  
}   

if (mail($sendTo, $subject, $msg, $headers)) 
{
    if (isset($successRedirect)) 
    {
        echo "$successRedirect";
        header("location: $successRedirect");
        exit();
    } 
} 
else 
{
    echo "<hr/>An error occured with the email notification system. <br/><br/><hr/><br/><a href=\"$errorRedirect\">Click here to return</a><br/>";  
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had actually started off embedding the image in the HTML I send but it would be more convenient for my employer to deal with an attachment (I know, I know - right click save as - don't get me started) and I aim to please. I will play around with some of the code you provided and see if any of the snippets can help.

Comment: This code works for me however I think my problem has to do with my multipart MIME formatting which is necessary to include an attached image (rather than an embedded one). Thanks again!

Comment: Which server environment are you using, and which version of PHP? Have you tried boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$your_hash."\" ?

Comment: I looked around a bit, this worked fine for .zip files. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php  Will likely have to change Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip" to match your attachment type, like Content-Type: image/png  etc. Good luck!